# php does not echo back POST data

Tags: php, jquery

I have the following jQuery script to post form data to php.  I'm testing the form data with a simple php file to echo back the firstname field of the input post:datastring as a test (I'm new to using php so that's why I'm testing it).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#btn_submit").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    form_data = $('form').serialize()
    var datastring = JSON.stringify({form_data});
    console.log("Okay, I'm starting");
    console.log(form_data);
    console.log(datastring);
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "echo_test.php",
        data: {post: datastring},
        success: function (responseText) {
            console.log(responseText);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log("Okay, I failed" + error);
        }
    });
});
```

The simple php file:

```
<?php
echo 'Hello ' . htmlspecialchars($_POST["firstname"]) . '!';
?>
```

Here's what the Firefox dev console echoes back:

```
Okay, I'm starting
email_field=mj%40abc.com&firstname=mary&lastname=jones&comments=no+comment%0D%0A
{"form_data":"email_field=mj%40abc.com&firstname=mary&lastname=jones&comments=no+comment%0D%0A"}
```

and finally it echoes back:

```
Hello !
```

So the Hello part and the exclamation point are echoed back, but not the firstname field.  I can see that the datastring it posts to the php file does contain firstname=mary, so there is a value in that field.

Why doesn't the firstname field echo back?

Comment: look like you nested `datastring` inside `post`, so you can try `$_POST['post']['firstname']`

Comment: Do you mean to change "data: {post: datastring}" to "data: {$_POST['post']['firstname'] }" - because there are more fields than just firstname.

Comment: This example shows how you can post firstname...  data: {
      firstname: 'name' } then in php  $_POST["firstname"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not posting your data correctly, try this :

```
$("#btn_submit").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    form_data = $('form').serialize()
    console.log("Okay, I'm starting");
    console.log(form_data);
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "echo_test.php",
        data: form_data,
        success: function (responseText) {
            console.log(responseText);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log("Okay, I failed" + error);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Okay, I'll try that and post back.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use

```
data: {post: datastring},
```

the `datastring` value will be in `$_POST['post']`. It will be encoded as JSON, so you'll need to call `json_decode()` to decode it.

But you calso use `form_data = $('form').serialize()`. `form_data` will therefore be in URL-encoded format. You'll need to use `parse_str()` to decode this.

And the syntax `{form_data}` is shorthand for `{form_data: form_data}`, so you'll have to access the `form_data` property of the decoded JSON.

So the PHP needs to be:

```
<?php
$datastring = $_POST['post'];
$datastring_decoded = json_decode($datastring);
$form_data = datastring_decoded->form_data;
$params = parse_str($form_data);
$firstname = $params['firstname'];
echo "Hello $firstname";
```

It would have been much simpler if you just used

```
data: form_data,
```

in the `$.ajax()` call. Then the parameter would be in `$_POST['firstname']`. There's rarely any need to use JSON when posting with `$.ajax()`, unless you're calling an API that specifically requires this instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` format.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'm working on Ugo T.'s example now.  It has to be re-sent to the cloud so it will take a few minutes.  I'll post back with my results.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: as you said, data: form_data is the right choice, as Ugo T. said in his answer.

Comment: I know. I wanted to explain in detail what's actually happening in your code.

Comment: You asked **Why doesn't the firstname field echo back?** His answer doesn't answer that question, mine does.

Comment: I copied his code and it worked, so that's why I chose his as best answer.  I'm sorry SO doesn't allow me to choose two best answers because yours is just as good.  I upvoted your answer.